# initialize a scope variable with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I'm always using `ng-init="controllerFunction()"` to get data from the server and display it on a table, chart or anything else and it needs to get called on every page loading.

Now using `ng-init` is doing the job but is it the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` is mainly used to pass data to an init method, for example razor data (`ng-init="someControllerFunction(@Model.ServerSideData)`). If you don't pass any data you can just do it directly in your controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    function myInitFunction(){
        // fetch data etc.
    }

    myInitFunction();
}
```

This way you don't expose the init function and is nicely encapsulated inside your controller.

Comment: Yeah but then If I want to initialize a function on a specific view but not the other I need to do more than just that which `ng-init` provides without any further work.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) clearly states (in a big red alert) that `ngInit` has only a few focused use-cases, and should not be used outside of these scenarios

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

Comment: then could you suggest what's the best practice to call data on page loading.